# Sails.js lazy loading models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, lazy-loading

Let's say I'm having a question model that contains many choices to answer, basically a one question to many choices.
Sails automatically exposes a RESTful list view for both the question and choice model, but each of those endpoints automatically also lists all associated relations like so:

Calling `GET /question`:

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "createdAt": 1520183091725,
      "updatedAt": 1520183091725,
      "id": 1,
      "text": "This is an answer",
      "votes": 1,
      "associatedQuestion": 1
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": 1520183061263,
  "updatedAt": 1520183061263,
  "id": 1,
  "text": "This is a question"
}
```

That's all fine until my `choice` model gets new relations itself, therefore nesting the list again.

Is there any way to tell Sails which attributes should not get sent in the default REST route? I figured that I can create a method on my `QuestionController` that uses `find`, which would then only return a flat list of `question` objects. But is that a good practice?

Comment: Yes, in my experience routes will only get you so far. For everything else creating your own controller is the way to go.

Comment: So would you recommend not to enable blueprints in production as they don't support paging and responses can get inefficiently large?

Comment: Yes and no, with sails you can deactivate blueprint routes on a per controller basis. Like I said for some requests, the only way to go is with your own controller functionality. And with blueprints you can page, use limit and skip.

Comment: Can I force a blueprint to limit or page on a per controller basis, so that every request only returns x results on default? Thank you for the input

Comment: You can set the limit either for all blueprints using `defaultLimit : 20` in config/blueprints.js or on individual routes using `"GET /model": {blueprint: populate_limit: 20}` in config/routes.js

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful. Unfortunately the documentation is relatively hard to grasp imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced in the comments; for more complex queries on your dataset/database, it makes a lot of sense to create an action in your controller. Actions are bound to routes in your application, so that when a client requests the route, the action is executed to perform some business logic and send a response.

With regards to your concerns:

> That's all fine until my choice model gets new relations itself,
>   therefore nesting the list again.

If you are using a Sails version < v1. Sails only populates one model deep. Nested population is not included. So no worries there.

If you are using Sails >= v1. You can create your own controller action to limit this. Database dependent, this could be done using the Waterline query language or if using a RDMS, the .native()/.query() methods make a direct call to the underlying database driver. For example, using MySQL:

```
Question.query("SELECT * " +
    "FROM   question " +
    "      JOIN choices " +
    "        ON question.id = choices.id " +
    "WHERE  question.id = "+req.param('id')+"; ").exec...
```

Off the topic but relevant to our discussion in the comments.

To limit the number of results returned from a route or action controller, you can:

Set a global defaultLimit in config/blueprints.js

```
defaultLimit: 20
```

Set the limit on a route by route basis in config/routes.js

```
"GET /question": {blueprint: populate_limit: 20}
```

Or using the url parameters in the request

```
"&limit=10"
```

Comment: Thanks once again. I'm currently using version 1.0-beta as it's the final release candidate. The syntax you're providing for the routing is incorrect though, can you provide the correct one? I guess you wanted to nest populate_limit: 20 in another object, but this still doesn't work for me in 1.0.

Comment: Looks like it is covered at https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints now. Scroll down to the section Using parseBlueprintOptions for an example on setting limits.